# Geoserver issue with big raster

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, jvm, geoserver

General Cluster Information:

Kubernetes version: 1.19.13
Cloud being used: private
Installation method: kubeadm init
Host OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
CNI and version: Weave Net: 2.7.0
CRI and version: Docker: 19.3.13

I have some trouble running geoserver 2.20.2 (stable version) on my kubernetes cluster. I created the Docker image from scratch as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR /root
RUN apt update; apt install wget -y; apt install unzip -y;  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive TZ=Europe/Berlin apt install openjdk-11-jdk -y; apt install postgis postgresql-client-12 gdal-bin -y
RUN wget https://phoenixnap.dl.sourceforge.net/project/geoserver/GeoServer/2.20.2/geoserver-2.20.2-bin.zip; unzip geoserver-2.20.2-bin.zip; rm geoserver-2.20.2-bin.zip;
RUN wget https://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/geoserver/GeoServer/2.17.5/extensions/geoserver-2.17.5-imagemosaic-jdbc-plugin.zip; unzip geoserver-2.17.5-imagemosaic-jdbc-plugin.zip; rm geoserver-2.17.5-imagemosaic-jdbc-plugin.zip; mv gt-imagemosaic-jdbc-23.5.jar webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/
RUN wget https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.20.x/community-latest/geoserver-2.20-SNAPSHOT-pgraster-plugin.zip; unzip geoserver-2.20-SNAPSHOT-pgraster-plugin.zip; rm geoserver-2.20-SNAPSHOT-pgraster-plugin.zip; mv gs-pgraster-2.20-SNAPSHOT.jar webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/; 
CMD bash ./bin/startup.sh
```

My aim is to offer a wms for accessing raster data stored in a postgresql database (with postgis extension)

therefore, I first created the database and the postgis extension

```
createdb -U postgres -h databasehost  geotest
psql -U postgres -d geotest -h databasehost -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
```

Afterwards, I combined all raster files in a vrt-file

```
for file in *.tif 
do
        echo $file
        gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:25832 -overwrite $file neu_${file}
        rm $file
        mv neu_$file $file
done
gdalbuildvrt composite.vrt *.tif
```

I created a folder tiles and execute gdal_retile to retile the created raster file

```
mkdir tiles
gdal_retile.py -co "WORLDFILE=YES" -r bilinear -ps 100 100 -of GTIFF -levels 4 -targetDir tiles composite.vrt
```

Subsequently, I created three files, as mentioned in the docs of geoserver

```
#connect.postgis.xml.inc
<connect>
  <!-- value DBCP or JNDI -->
  <dstype value="DBCP"/>
  <!--   <jndiReferenceName value=""/>  -->
  <username value="postgres" />
  <password value="password" />
  <jdbcUrl value="jdbc:postgresql://databasehost:5432/geotest" />
  <driverClassName value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
  <maxActive value="10"/>
  <maxIdle value="0"/>
</connect>

#mapping.postgis.xml.inc
<!-- possible values: universal,postgis,db2,mysql,oracle -->
<spatialExtension name="postgis"/>
<mapping>
    <masterTable name="mosaic" >
      <coverageNameAttribute name="name"/>
      <maxXAttribute name="maxX"/>
      <maxYAttribute name="maxY"/>
      <minXAttribute name="minX"/>
      <minYAttribute name="minY"/>
      <resXAttribute name="resX"/>
      <resYAttribute name="resY"/>
      <tileTableNameAtribute  name="TileTable" />
      <spatialTableNameAtribute name="SpatialTable" />
    </masterTable>
    <tileTable>
      <blobAttributeName name="data" />
      <keyAttributeName name="location" />
    </tileTable>
    <spatialTable>
      <keyAttributeName name="location" />
      <geomAttributeName name="geom" />
      <tileMaxXAttribute name="maxX"/>
      <tileMaxYAttribute name="maxY"/>
      <tileMinXAttribute name="minX"/>
      <tileMinYAttribute name="minY"/>
    </spatialTable>
</mapping>

#dgm.postgis.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ImageMosaicJDBCConfig [
  <!ENTITY mapping PUBLIC "mapping"  "mapping.postgis.xml.inc">
  <!ENTITY connect PUBLIC "connect"  "connect.postgis.xml.inc">]>
<config version="1.0">
  <coverageName name="dgm"/>
  <coordsys name="EPSG:25832"/>
  <!-- interpolation 1 = nearest neighbour, 2 = bilinear, 3 = bicubic -->
  <scaleop  interpolation="1"/>
  <verify cardinality="false"/>
  &mapping;
  &connect;
</config>
```

Than I created a new folder for storing the postgresql files to create the necessary database tables and created the tables

```
mkdir sqlscripts
java -jar ~/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-imagemosaic-jdbc-23.5.jar ddl -config dgm.postgis.xml -spatialTNPrefix dgm -pyramids 4 -statementDelim ";" -srs 25832 -targetDir sqlscripts

psql -U postgres -d geotest -h databasehost -f sqlscripts/createmeta.sql
psql -U postgres -d geotest -h databasehost -f sqlscripts/add_dgm.sql
```

finally, I pushed the rastertiles to the database and copied the three configuration file mentioned above to the following directory: /root/data_dir/coverages/dgm

```
java -classpath /root/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-imagemosaic-jdbc-23.5.jar:/root/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/postgresql-42.2.19.jar:/root/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-jdbc-postgis-26.2.jar org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.Toolbox import -config dgm.postgis.xml -spatialTNPrefix dgm -tileTNPrefix dgm -dir tiles/ -ext tif
mkdir /root/data_dir/coverage/dgm
cp *.xml* /root/data_dir/coverages/dgm
```

Finally, I configured the datastore with the browser client. For small raster tables this works well. But for bigger tables I receive the following error:

> Failed to create reader from file:coverages/dgm/dgm.postgis.xml and
> hints Hints: STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl
> FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true
> GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null
> REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@66c9b911
> FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http
> COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 EXECUTOR_SERVICE =
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4137b934[Running, pool size =
> 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
> FEATURE_FACTORY =
> org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@44de94c3

I already increased the jvm heap size. Nevertheless, I am getting the error above. Can someone help me, how I need to configure the geoserver, that I can work with it, also with big raster tiles, stored in a postgresql database?

For every hint I am grateful.

Best Regards

**EDIT 1:**
After setting in global setting the log-level to developer I receive the following output message in the browser:

> Failed to create reader from file:coverages/dgm/dgm.postgis.xml and
> hints Hints: STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl
> FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true
> GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null
> REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@360a7fe7
> FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http
> COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 EXECUTOR_SERVICE =
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@65d3cd0b[Running, pool size =
> 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
> FEATURE_FACTORY =
> org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@44de94c3

The log file looks like this:

> 2022-03-03 20:33:32,429 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] -
> polling contents of /root/data_dir/gwc-layers 2022-03-03 20:33:36,632
> TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 3,878ms
> for /root/data_dir/gwc-layers 2022-03-03 20:33:41,459 ERROR
> [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc] - Ran out of memory retrieving
> query results. org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ran out of memory
> retrieving query results.     at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2256)
> at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
> at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)    at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
> at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
> at
> org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
> at
> org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
> at
> org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.JDBCAccessBase.getPixelResolution(JDBCAccessBase.java:696)
> at
> org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.JDBCAccessBase.calculateResolutionsFromDB(JDBCAccessBase.java:433)
> at
> org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.JDBCAccessBase.initialize(JDBCAccessBase.java:121)
> at
> org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.JDBCAccessFactory.getJDBCAcess(JDBCAccessFactory.java:90)
> at
> org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.ImageMosaicJDBCReader.(ImageMosaicJDBCReader.java:144)
> at
> org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.ImageMosaicJDBCFormat.getReader(ImageMosaicJDBCFormat.java:197)
> at
> org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.ImageMosaicJDBCFormat.getReader(ImageMosaicJDBCFormat.java:59)
> at
> org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1573)
> at
> org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1518)
> at
> org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1505)
>
> . . . cut some log messages
>
> at
> org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior$AjaxFormSubmitter.onSubmit(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:218)
> at
> org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1312)
> at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:976)   at
> org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:797)
> at
> org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
> at
> org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> 2022-03-03 20:33:41,460 ERROR [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc] -
> Ran out of memory retrieving query results. 2022-03-03 20:33:41,461
> ERROR [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc] -
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ran out of memory retrieving query
> results. 2022-03-03 20:33:41,461 WARN
> [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc] - java.io.IOException:
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ran out of memory retrieving query
> results. java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException:
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ran out of memory retrieving query
> results.  at
> org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.ImageMosaicJDBCReader.(ImageMosaicJDBCReader.java:147)
> at
> org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.ImageMosaicJDBCFormat.getReader(ImageMosaicJDBCFormat.java:197)
> at
> org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.ImageMosaicJDBCFormat.getReader(ImageMosaicJDBCFormat.java:59)
> at
> org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1573)
> at
> org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1518)
> at
> org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1505)
> at
> org.geoserver.web.data.store.CoverageStoreEditPage.onSave(CoverageStoreEditPage.java:126)
> at
> org.geoserver.web.data.store.AbstractCoverageStorePage$1.onSubmit(AbstractCoverageStorePage.java:138)
> at
> org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink$1.onSubmit(AjaxSubmitLink.java:111)
> at
> org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior$AjaxFormSubmitter.onSubmit(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:218)
> at
> org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1312)
> at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:976)
>
> . . . cut some log messages
>
> at
> org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1518)
> at
> org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1505)
> at
> org.geoserver.web.data.store.CoverageStoreEditPage.onSave(CoverageStoreEditPage.java:126)
> at
> org.geoserver.web.data.store.AbstractCoverageStorePage$1.onSubmit(AbstractCoverageStorePage.java:138)
> at
> org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink$1.onSubmit(AjaxSubmitLink.java:111)
> at
> org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior$AjaxFormSubmitter.onSubmit(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:218)
> at
> org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1312)
> at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:976)   at
> org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:797)
> at
> org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
> at
> org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> 2022-03-03 20:33:41,517 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 16 locking in
> mode READ 2022-03-03 20:33:41,517 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 16
> releasing the lock in mode READ 2022-03-03 20:33:41,583 DEBUG
> [org.geoserver.filters] - Compressing output for mimetype:
> text/xml;charset=utf-8 2022-03-03 20:33:41,584 DEBUG
> [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1]
>
> - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed 2022-03-03 20:33:43,728 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] -
>   polling contents of /root/data_dir/gwc-layers 2022-03-03 20:33:43,729
>   TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 709us for
>   /root/data_dir/gwc-layers 2022-03-03 20:33:48,730 TRACE
>   [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of
>   /root/data_dir/gwc-layers

**EDIT 2:** adjustment of the jvm heap size

JAVA_OPTS="-Xms20000m -Xmx20000m"

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: also I think your VRT should be built with the `neu_xxxx.tif` files (i.e. the ones you reprojected). and you seem to be building a mosaic on a pyramid folder - there should be no need for the pyramid unless your number of tiles exceeds a 100 and each tile is >2Gb.

Comment: So, we also need the sizes (on average) of the tiles and what size the image would be if you translated the vrt to a geotif.

Comment: @IanTurton 1) thanks for your comments and your time! 2) added the relevant part, and output on the website. 3) The vrt-file is built with the neu_xxxx.tif. I remove the old file and mv the new file to the same location and the same name as the old file. The number of tiles is about 32,000 each tile have about 4 Mb. 4) I guess about 128 GB. But I also have the same number of high resolution imagery with about 50 MB/tile in average which I also wanna offer as wms. But if I struggle already with the small dataset, the bigger one will most probably not work too.